# Laravel: Localized Inspiring quote

Tags: php, laravel, localization

Is it possible to get a localized (German) version from `Inspiring::quote()` (in Laravel 5.3)?

I think this function is only for fun and internal testing purpose, because the API doc of the `Inspiring` class is quite minimal and says nothing about localization.

Comment: This command is just an example of how you can create your own commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up localization. You can read about that in the [Laravel Localization Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/localization). That would require manual translations for each quote.

To have something a bit more automated, consider using this package; https://github.com/potsky/laravel-localization-helpers Not sure if its compatible with 5.3 thou.